# increasing FPS using SharpAVI speeds the video

Tags: c#, video, frame-rate, avi, video-recording

I am using `SharpAVI` to record a screen, and I am using their sample `Recorder` which is here [Recoder Sample](https://sharpavi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Sample/Recorder.cs), the `AviWriter` in the sample has `FPS` of `10` when I increase it like for `30-60` and I play the video it becomes faster like I am speeding it, I can't understand how it gets faster like that and not getting more smooth!? What am I missing here?

Comment: If your video is 10 fps, and you play it at 60 fps, that means 6 seconds worth of frames will be crammed into 1 second, making the video go faster.

Comment: if it's 10fps it works kinda fine but not smooth when I increase the fps it goes faster!

Comment: Same issue here. Just starting to look into why. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @ickydime no not really, please let me know if you figured it out. thanks!

Comment: @MixedCoder did you get solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From SharpAvi's forums and issues pages it appears to be an issue with encoding performance in that the encoder can not keep up and drops frames.  Then it tries to play back at 60 frames per second when say it was only able to record at 20 fps and thus you get a fast video:

Issues Page:
https://sharpavi.codeplex.com/workitem/7

Forums Page:
https://sharpavi.codeplex.com/discussions/652304

On the issues page above the developer behind the project suggests some ways to improve performance via threading, etc.